# Wikidata query duplicates

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Sorry if my english is bad, but I don't really have any place where I can ask this question in my native language.
I've been trying to create SPARQL query for Wikidata that should create a list of all horror fiction that was created in 1925-1950 years, names of authors and, if available, pictures:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?author ?name ?creation ?picture
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P136 wd:Q193606 . # book
    ?item wdt:P50 ?author .   # author
    ?item wdt:P577 ?creation .
    ?item wdt:P577 ?end .
  ?author rdfs:label ?name .    
  OPTIONAL{ ?item wdt:P18 ?picture }
  FILTER (?creation >= "1925-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) .
  FILTER (?end <= "1950-12-31T23:59:59Z"^^xsd:dateTime) .

SERVICE wikibase:label
{ 
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
} 
}
```

However, for some reason this query placing duplicates in the list. DISTINCT doesn't do much. After some time I figured out that the reason is "?item rdfs:label ?name .". If this line is removed, no duplicates are listed. But I need this line to show author name in the list!
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `?item rdfs:label ?name .` as you already get items labels as `?itemLabel` thank to `SERVICE wikibase:label`.

Then, you will get duplicate results for every items that have a `SELECT`ed property with possibly multiple values: here, you are `SELECT`ing authors (P50), which will create duplicates for every item with several authors.

Comment: Uh-oh, my mistake. This line should be `?author rdfs:label ?name .`Without it, I don't get a name of an author, I get just a link.
What should I do to make it work properly?

Comment: then you should just need to `SELECT ?authorLabel` too, I guess

Comment: It worked! So simple, yet I don't think I would have figured that out by myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: more on the label service: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service

Answer (score 2):

The query is actually giving you distinct items. The problem is that some items have multiple rdfs:labels. You can see as an example the item:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
   wd:Q2882840 rdfs:label ?label

SERVICE wikibase:label
{ 
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
} 
}
```

And since there are multiple rdfs:label predicates for some items, they are showing up in separate rows.

Comment: So, I guess, there's no way to make this query work properly?

Comment: If there are multiple labels you get multiple rows back - that's how the semantics of SPARQL is defined. You could i) restrict the number of labels or ii) use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all labels into a single value.

Comment: I tried `{ select * where {?author rdfs:label ?name.} LIMIT 1}` instead of the line `?author rdfs:label ?name` but it does not seem to work (returns back no results); not sure why.

Comment: Found some examples of using `GROUP_CONCAT` via google but it won't work with my query, saying "Bad aggregate". 
Idea with `LIMIT` actually sounds nice. If only it would work, sigh.

Comment: @Dusk See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate your results according to the book title (the item's label) using the

> group by

keyword.
Thus, every result will be a group which will show up once, and other fields which have different values, will be aggregated using the separator (in this case, a comma).

The fixed query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel 
(group_concat(distinct ?author;separator=",") as ?author)
(group_concat(distinct ?name;separator=",") as ?name)
 (group_concat(distinct ?creation;separator=",") as ?creation)
 (group_concat(distinct ?picture;separator=",") as ?picture)
WHERE
{
    ?item wdt:P136 wd:Q193606 . # book
    ?item wdt:P50 ?author .   # author
    ?item wdt:P577 ?creation .
    ?item wdt:P577 ?end .
  ?author rdfs:label ?name .    
  OPTIONAL{ ?item wdt:P18 ?picture }
  FILTER (?creation >= "1925-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) .
  FILTER (?end <= "1950-12-31T23:59:59Z"^^xsd:dateTime) .

SERVICE wikibase:label
{ 
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
} 
}
group by ?item ?itemLabel
```

Comment: nice! thanks - this is on perfect way to handle duplicates, I got those often for instance when getting a list of personalities filtered by some property and they have more than one image in WikiData