# Limit Wikidata results to only one label where more are available

Tags: sparql, distinct, wikidata-query-service

I Have the following SPARQL query for Wikidata:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?location ?place_eng ?admin_eng ?country_eng WHERE {
  {
    VALUES ?place { wd:Q23154 wd:Q19319 wd:Q2758 }
    OPTIONAL { ?place wdt:P625 ?location. }
    ?place wdt:P131 ?admin.
    ?place wdt:P17 ?country.
  }

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?place rdfs:label ?place_eng.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?admin rdfs:label ?admin_eng.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_eng.
  }
}
```

Which selects three specific cities with their location and labels for name, administration name and country name. If you run the query in [Wikidata Query service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flocation%20%3Fplace_eng%20%3Fadmin_eng%20%3Fcountry_eng%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Fplace%20%7B%20wd%3AQ23154%20wd%3AQ19319%20wd%3AQ2758%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP131%20%3Fadmin.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fplace_eng.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fadmin%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fadmin_eng.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_eng.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) you can see that one of the cities appears twice, because there are two different labels available for its administration.

**How can I make sure each city appears only once?** In case there are multiple labels, I only care about getting one (the first one, or even at random, provided it's the same every time I run the query).

I've already tried this solution from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377359/wikidata-query-duplicates) (only the first line changes):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?location ?place_eng (group_concat(distinct ?admin_eng) as ?admin_eng) ?country_eng WHERE {
  {
    VALUES ?place { wd:Q23154 wd:Q19319 wd:Q2758 }
    OPTIONAL { ?place wdt:P625 ?location. }
    ?place wdt:P131 ?admin.
    ?place wdt:P17 ?country.
  }

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?place rdfs:label ?place_eng.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?admin rdfs:label ?admin_eng.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_eng.
  }
}
```

But I get a Bad Aggregate error.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?location (sample(?place_eng) as ?placeEng) (sample(?admin_eng) as ?adminEng) (sample(?country_eng) as ?countryEng) WHERE {
  
    VALUES ?place { wd:Q23154 wd:Q19319 wd:Q2758 }
    OPTIONAL { ?place wdt:P625 ?location. }
    ?place wdt:P131 ?admin.
    ?place wdt:P17 ?country.

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?place rdfs:label ?place_eng.
    ?admin rdfs:label ?admin_eng.
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_eng.
  }
 
} group by ?location`

Comment: Does this guarantee that the same label will be picked every time, if there are several?